# How to get last digits which are number before '.html' string

Tags: php, regex

there is a string, for example : http://address.com/sef-title-of-topic-**1111**.html

i could not get **1111** in anyway with regexp in php. Is it possible? How?

my code:

```
$address = 'http://address.com/sef-title-of-topic-1111.html';

preg_match('#-(.*?)\.html#sim',$address,$result);
```

Comment: Be more specific. Are the numbers a set length? Why can't you just use $_GET variables?

Comment: Is the URL always going to be in the format above? (with dashes, last for always digits etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the url example is how they will always appear (ie. ending in hyphen, numbers, .html) then this should work:

```
$str = "http://address.com/sef-title-of-topic-1111.html";

preg_match('#.*-(\d+)\.html#', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

If they won't always match the pattern you gave in your question, then clarify by showing alternative values for your `$address` value.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the extension is definitely .html (and not .htm for example) then you could use

```
$lastNos= substr($input, -9, -4);
```

Clearly a simple solution but you have not specified why regex is required.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL will always be in this format I would use str_replace to strip the .html then explode by "-" and find the last piece.

Of course all of that is assuming the URL is always in this format.

Answer (score 0):

If the format is always the same you dont need a regex.

```
$url = "http://address.com/sef-title-of-topic-1111.html";

echo $str = strrev(array_shift(array_reverse(explode(".", array_shift(explode("-",strrev($url)))))));
```

edit: sorry my php is a bit rusty